# Multi domain SSL in Apache - Error

Tags: ssl-certificate, apache2

I have an SSL certificate for multiple domains.
I configured apache like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost 
                DocumentRoot /var/www/satsure
                ServerName satsure.co 
                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined 
                SSLEngine on 
                SSLCertificateFile /home/ubuntu/cert/cert.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ubuntu/cert/statlogic.key
                SSLCertificateChainFile /home/ubuntu/cert/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt             
                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>  
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

But I am getting an error like this while starting the server.

```
[ssl:emerg] [pid 11124:tid 139745708714944] AH02565: Certificate and private key ip-172-31-2-51.ap-south-1.compute.internal:443:0 from /home/ubuntu/cert/cert.crt and /home/ubuntu/cert/statlogic.key do not match
```

But I am sure that I created the key correctly and is the same key
.
Could anyone please help??

Comment: You created the certificate and key? How? As this is a GoDaddy certificate (I assume), you shouldn't have to create anything.

Comment: first check if your key and certificate pair matches with each other, you can check with online tool https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-key-matcher.html. If its not matching, generate a new key/csr and use same key with newly generated certificate.

Comment: Rather than uploading both your private key and public cert an online service, you can also check with`openssl` on the system itself. `openssl rsa -check -noout -in statlogic.key` should return **RSA Key is ok** and the modulus of a private key and it's certificate should be identical: `openssl rsa -modulus -noout -in statlogic.key` and `openssl x509 -modulus -noout -in cert.crt` - when they are not identical the key does not belong with that certificate.

Comment: @Lenniey I generated the CSR from the server and uploaded that to GoDaddy to create the certificate. I got private key from there.

Comment: VaibhavPanmand and HBruijn Thanks. I will check the key